# Facebook login button not accepting permissions upon click

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I've got the following at the top of my app's homepage URL.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '123456789',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true, 
            oauth: true 
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if(response.status === 'connected') {
                if(response.authResponse != 'undefined'){
                    window.location = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>register';
                }
            } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized')
            {
                //it means we have a user but he hasn't granted any permissions to our app
                //we're going to redirect him to the permission page
                window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=456109407732505&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<?php echo $base_url; ?>register&scope=email,publish_actions,user_likes';
            } else 
            {
                //the user is not logged in, as you already have a login button you don't have to do nothing  
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            window.location = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>register';
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" 
    data-show-faces="false" 
    data-scope="email,publish_actions,manage_notifications,user_likes" 
    size="large" 
    data-width="200" 
    data-max-rows="1">
</div>
```

The only time that this code throws an error is when the user viewing the site is logged into FB but hasn't accepted the app's permissions. In that case, the user will be redirected to the link specified in the JS ("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=456109407732505&response_type=code&redirect_uri=register&scope=email,publish_actions,user_likes") where they can choose to either accept or reject the requested permissions. If the user chooses to accept the permissions thru that link, then everything goes just fine. However, upon click of the FB login button, a pop will appear that also gives the user a chance to accept or reject the permissions. Upon acceptance of the requested permissions on the pop up, for some reason the user's email isn't fetched. The user is redirected to the register.php file and an error is thrown. However, when the register.php page is refreshed, it works just fine.

[image: FB Pop up that doesn't complete registration]

In my register.php file. I have

```
require_once('application/third_party/facebook_api/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => '123456789',
                                'secret' => 'app_secret',
                                'cookie' => true));
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if($access_token != '') 
{
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user != 0)
    {
//      Get the user's info
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$user);  

//      Get the user's permissions 
        $perms = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/permissions');  
        $perms = $perms['data'][0];
        $installed = $perms['installed'];

        if($installed == 1)
        {
            $fb_first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
            $fb_last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];

//              Find out if they accepted the email permission
            $email_perm = $perms['email'];

            if($email_perm == 1)
            {
                $fb_email = $user_profile['email'];
            } else
            {
                $fb_email = '';
            }
       }
  }
```

PHP is throwing me an error reading "undefined index 'email'."It works upon refreshing the page, but not the first time. You can go to [my app](https://www.sportannica.com/) to see a working example.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should "can" not mix read and write permissions anymore
with the login button
you have to get just basic and read, then in your flow of the site ask for write when needed

---

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

> Here are a few guidelines to use when asking for permissions, both
>   during and after login:
>
> Only ask for the permissions that are essential to an app.
>
> Ask for permission in the context in which they are required. For
>   example, if your app wants to show places of interest near a person's
>   home, asking for user_location just prior to displaying that
>   information would give the person a greater understanding of why the
>   permission is being requested.
>
> Use any available public profile information before asking for a
>   permission. For example, there is an age_range field included in the
>   public profile for anyone who installs your app. This field may be
>   sufficient for your app instead of requesting user_birthday
>   permission.
>
> Separate the request of read and publish permissions. For more
>   details, see below.
>
> Never ask for permissions you think you might need in the future.
>   People will be suspicious and may reject your app.